# Column Apply in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to multiply two pandas data_frames with varying number of columns and I would like to end up with a resulting data_frame in the shape of the first data_frame. i.e. if the row and column matches multiple the two cells, otherwise keep the value as in the first data frame. Examples below:
What is the most efficient matrix form approach that will not require a for loop?

Thank you!

df1:

[image]

df2:

[image]

resulting df (df_result = df1 * df2):

[image]

Comment: slice the df2 by using the index and columns from df1

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1**
Use `pd.DataFrame.align`

```
pd.DataFrame.mul(*df1.align(df2, 'left', fill_value=1))

             X     Y     Z
1/1/2017  0.26  0.94  0.22
1/3/2017   NaN  0.63  0.78
1/5/2017  0.73  0.79  0.25
1/6/2017  0.13   NaN  0.31
```

---

**Option 2**
Use `pd.DataFrame.reindex`

```
df1 * df2.reindex(df1.index, df1.columns, fill_value=1)

             X     Y     Z
1/1/2017  0.26  0.94  0.22
1/3/2017   NaN  0.63  0.78
1/5/2017  0.73  0.79  0.25
1/6/2017  0.13   NaN  0.31
```

---

**Option 3**
Use `pd.DataFrame.mask`
As recommended by commenter @CedricZoppolo:
*Warning:*  This is making an assumption that the values of `1` are intended to mark valid positions, like a mask.  This doesn't multiply the values.  If the intention is to truly multiply values, then don't use this option.

```
df1.mask(df2.isnull().reindex_like(df1).fillna(False))

             X     Y     Z
1/1/2017  0.26  0.94  0.22
1/3/2017   NaN  0.63  0.78
1/5/2017  0.73  0.79  0.25
1/6/2017  0.13   NaN  0.31
```

---

---

**Setup**

```
from numpy import nan as NA

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    X=[0.26, 0.45, 0.73, 0.13],
    Y=[0.94, 0.63, 0.79, 0.16],
    Z=[0.22, 0.78, 0.25, 0.31]
), ['1/1/2017', '1/3/2017', '1/5/2017', '1/6/2017'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    X=[1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1],
    XX=[NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1],
    Y=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA],
    Y1=[NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA],
    YY=[NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1]
), ['1/1/2017', '1/2/2017', '1/3/2017', '1/4/2017', '1/5/2017', '1/6/2017'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: But this does not multiply the values. What happens if you have values of lets say `2` under `df2` instead? Output would not be as expected...

Comment: @CedricZoppolo then don't use option 3... stick to options 1 or 2.  In those options I fill with `1` which will leave those cells alone.

Comment: Right. Then option three should have a warning ;) These one liners are still kind of magic to me. Do you recommend any tutorial for learning to create such?

Comment: I added warning.

Answer (score 0):

Do not have a single line solution, but the following should work and no loops are involved.

```
# First DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['A'] = [1,2,3]
df1['B'] = [2,4,6]
df1['C'] = [3,6,9]

# Second DataFrame
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['A'] = [1,2,3]
df2['B'] = [2,4,6]
df2['D'] = [3,6,9]

common_cols = list(set(df2.columns) & set(df1.columns))
left_only_cols = list(set(df1.columns) - set(df2.columns))

res_df = df1[common_cols]*df2[common_cols]
res_df[left_only_cols] = df1[left_only_cols]

print res_df
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the shared columns, then slice both data frames using this, and then multiply:

```
In [47]: df1
Out[47]:
   X  Y  Z
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9

In [48]: df2
Out[48]:
   X  XX   Y  Y1  YY
0  1   2 NaN   4 NaN
1  4   5 NaN   4   5
2  7   8   9   2   3

In [49]: shared_cols = [col for col in df1.columns if col in df2.columns]

In [50]: shared_cols
Out[50]: ['X', 'Y']

In [51]: df1[shared_cols] * df2[shared_cols]
Out[51]:
    X   Y
0   1 NaN
1  16 NaN
2  49  72
```

Comment: Here `Z` column is missing in the output

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include that in the 2nd dataframe but that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary `Dataframe` for `df2` adding a column of `1`s when the column of `df1` is not present. Then multiply the dataframes and finally selecting the range on output using the index and columns of `df1` as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Date":["1/1/2017","1/3/2017","1/5/2017","1/6/2017"],
"X":[0.26,0.45,0.73,0.13],
"Y":[0.94,0.63,0.79,0.16],
"Z":[0.22,0.78,0.25,0.31]})
df1["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Date"])
df1 = df1.set_index(["Date"])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Date":["1/1/2017","1/2/2017","1/3/2017","1/4/2017","1/5/2017","1/6/2017"],
"X":[1,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1],
"XX":[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1, 1],
"Y":[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, np.nan],
"Y1":[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan],
"YY":[np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1]})
df2["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Date"])
df2 = df2.set_index(["Date"])

df2_tmp = df2.copy()
for col in df1.columns:
    if col not in df2.columns:
        df2_tmp[col] = 1
df_out = df1*df2_tmp
df_out = df_out.loc[df1.index,df1.columns]
```

So if your input is:

```
>>> df1
               X     Y     Z
Date                        
2017-01-01  0.26  0.94  0.22
2017-01-03  0.45  0.63  0.78
2017-01-05  0.73  0.79  0.25
2017-01-06  0.13  0.16  0.31
>>> df2
              X   XX    Y   Y1   YY
Date                               
2017-01-01  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
2017-01-02  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0
2017-01-03  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
2017-01-04  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2017-01-05  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
2017-01-06  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
```

Your output will be:

```
>>> df_out
               X     Y     Z
Date                        
2017-01-01  0.26  0.94  0.22
2017-01-03   NaN  0.63  0.78
2017-01-05  0.73  0.79  0.25
2017-01-06  0.13   NaN  0.31
```